# CloudFlare 525 Handshake SSL failed after ubuntu update

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, digital-ocean, cloudflare, handshake

I have 2 servers up at DigitalOcean. Both each have 2 sites with SSL & DNS setup via Cloudflare. They're all the same setup (nginx).

Yesterday after upgrading one of the server, I started getting error while trying to access the two site, 525 SSL handshake failed. While the 2 sites on the server that has not been updated work fine.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64)

Here are the packages that were updated :

```
apt
apt-transport-https
apt-utils
bind9-host
dnsutils
isc-dhcp-client
isc-dhcp-common
libapt-inst1.5
libapt-pkg4.12
libbind9-90
libdbd-mysql-perl
libdns100
libisc95
libisccc90
libisccfg90
liblwres90
libpython3.4-minimal
libpython3.4-stdlib
libssl-dev
libssl-doc
libssl1.0.0
linux-libc-dev
ntp
ntpdate
openssl
php5-cli
php5-common
php5-curl
php5-fpm
php5-gd
php5-mysql
php5-readline
python3-update-manager
python3.4
python3.4-minimal
tzdata
update-manager-core
```

I've been trying to find how one of these could have broken the sites, didn't. Looks like the link could be with openssl or apt-transport-https. Anyone experiencing similar issues ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things to check in your scenario, though the Cloudflare Knowledge Base has some additional [525 error debugging steps](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed) which may be of use to you.

It may be the case that the [cipher suites that Cloudflare accepts](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933580-What-cipher-suites-does-CloudFlare-use-for-SSL-) and the cipher suites that the origin server uses do not match. Cloudflare only supports TLS 1, 1.1 and 1.2 (with TLS 1.3 in beta); the legacy SSLv3 or SSLv2 protocols are not supported. Cloudflare also support a restricted list of ciphers. Ensure your version of OpenSSL supports the [cipher suites that Cloudflare support](https://github.com/cloudflare/sslconfig).

Also ensure that if Cloudflare SSL configuration is set to "Full", your origin server needs to be able to accept inbound SSL connections, if it is set to "Full (Strict)" your webserver needs to have either a signed certificate or a [Cloudflare Origin CA certificate](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/) installed on. Only in Flexible SSL mode does Cloudflare terminate SSL connections.

It is a good idea to test your SSL configuration, direct to your origin web server to see what the issue is; using OpenSSL you can check if it's possible to make a connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect [origin server IP]:443
```

You can then test for TLSv1 support using:

```
openssl s_client -connect [origin server IP]:443 -tls1
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I get this error, you have any ideas what it means ? CONNECTED(00000003)
73522:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:

Comment: Btw, the option is set to FULL in cloudflare and it was working fine prior update. The cipher suite is well set in my nginx config.

Comment: If I run `openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443 -tls1` I get this : `CONNECTED(00000003)
74077:error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 80
74077:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:`

Comment: What is the output if you login to the server and run ````openssl version````?

Comment: Here it is : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, looks like I fixed it... not sure how and no idea why this all went broken after update.